# Adding a Object to a firebase realtime database list turns it to an HashMap. How to keep it as a List or convert it

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I added a JSON to firebase realtime database and when I retrieved it it all goes smooth until I add a new element to the list through the app and it transforms it on a Hashmap.

How can I mantain it as a list.

```
 override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

    val database = p0.getValue(ListOfGamesJavaModel::class.java)!!
    val lastUpdate = database.date
}
```

This works fine before I add new elements to list

```
val newGameRef = database.child("gamesList")
    newGameRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis().toString()).setValue(game)
    database.child("date").setValue("23-08-2019 20:32")
```

After that when I run the code to retrieve the list I get this error.

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap

Can you help me retrieve it as a List

**Working**

[image: database - Working]

**NOT WORKING**

[image: database - Not - Working]

**UPDATE**

If I add it like this it works, but I'm trying to add a new one without knowing the list size.

```
val newGameRef = database.child("gamesList")
    newGameRef.child(int.toString()).setValue(game)
    database.child("date").setValue("23-08-2019 20:32")
```

Comment: Why don’t you convert the hashmap to a list?

Comment: can you add the JSON structure from you firebase console before adding an object and after to be able to help you?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo added, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database it always stores data as key-value pairs, with the keys being strings. In Java this translates to a `Map<String,Object>`. In some cases the Firebase clients are able to automatically convert the data to an array, which translates to `List<Object>` in your case. But in your second JSON screenshot, the client will not automatically convert the data to a `List`, so you'll have to do that yourself.

As Constantin commented, start by getting the `Map<String, ...>` from the database, and then get the list of values from that.

```
override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
    val map = p0.getValue(MapOfGamesJavaModel::class.java)!!
    val database = map.values
    val lastUpdate = database.date
}
```

The `MapOfGamesJavaModel` is a new class you'll have to create. Alternatively you can read `Map<String, GamesJavaModel>`, but you may have to do some casting with generic types in that case.

To learn more the way Firebase Realtime Database works with arrays, see [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: I actualy just did something similir and I was just going to update it but lets just mark yours as the correct answer